# sympy solveset returns FiniteSet in one case but a Complement in another case

Tags: python, sympy

So I am starting with an equality of an equation and a fraction that I use to solve for both x and y:

```
mrs = y/x
ratio = 2/5
x = sympy.solveset(sympy.Eq(mrs, ratio), x)
y = sympy.solveset(sympy.Eq(mrs, ratio), y)
```

In the end, solving for y returns:

```
￼￼{2*x/5}
```

Which is a FiniteSet

But solving for x returns:

```
{5*y/2} \ {0}
```

Which is a Complement

I don't get why solving for one variable gives me a FiniteSet when solving for the other doesn't do the same? Also, would there be a way to solve for the other variable so as to get a FiniteSet instead of a Complement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect as a result? Could you solve this problem by hand and write the expected solution? And why would you want a FiniteSet as solution?

I myself can not come up with a better notation than sympy, since `x=0` needs to be excluded.

When you continue working with the solutions sympy can easily work with both, FiniteSet and Complement. Mathematically those are not completely different structures. The difference is that sympy somehow needs to represent these solutions internally and can not use the same construction for everything, but rather uses small building blocks to create the solution. The result you get with `type(x)` is symply the last building block used.

**EDIT**: Some math here: `x=0` does not solve the equation `y/x=2/5` for any `y`. So this must be excluded from the solutionset.

If you solve for `y`, then `x=0` is already excluded since `y/0` is not well defined.

If you solve for `y`, then `y=0` is a priori possible, since `0/x=0` for `x!=0`. Thus sympy needs to exclude `x=0` manually, which it does by removing `0` from the set of solutions.

Now, since we know that `x=0` can never be a solution of the equation we can exclude it before even trying to solve the equation. Therefore we do

```
x = sympy.symbols('x', real=True, nonzero=True)
```

right at the beginning of the example (before the definition of mrs). The rest can remain unchanged.

Comment: So really I am looking to get a Finiteset since I know how to access the answers I get so that I can substitute them back into another equation I have. When I do this problem on paper I just cross multiply so I can find both x and y. This means that I was expecting just {5*y/2} and not the complement set sympy gives me.

Comment: Really? I do get something different. {5*y/2} includes y=0 and thus x=0. but calculating mrs=y/x=0/0 is not well defined (and especially not 2/5), so really y=0, x=0 is not a valid soluton.

Comment: Changing the arguments for x did the trick! Thanks a lot, mate!!